# How to add hibernate support for IntelliJ community edition?

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm new to Hibernate framework and mainly familiar with IntelliJ IDE. I understand that IntelliJ community edition does not provide Hibernate framework support by default.

Is there another way to include Hibernate into an IntelliJ project separately ?

Comment: It depends on what you expect from this support. In a Maven or Gradle based project you'll be able to build and run it, but you will not get any of the smart features or database support provided by the Ultimate.