# How to use Hibernate with IntelliJ community edition?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

As we know, the Hibernate is supported only in Ultimate Edition of Intellij IDEA. This point is stressed in [similar unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728842/how-to-add-hibernate-support-for-intellij-community-edition) too. So I'd like to achieve a *partial* result with my Community Edition. Namely, I want to create conditions *to build and run* my RDBMS application. No word about the full spectra of IDEA support of RDBMS development.

To enable Hibernate we have to (according to [Intellij support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-hibernate-support.html)):

1) Create a Hibernate configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml.

2) Download the library files that implement the Hibernate framework and add them to the dependencies of the corresponding module.

Is it the right way? If so - what are the libraries I have to download (I intend to use JPA)?

Answer (score 5):

In the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/enabling-hibernate-support.html), they say that:

> This feature is supported in the Ultimate edition only.

Answer (score 2):

You can empower your IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition using the JPA Buddy plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15075-jpa-buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use Hibernate with IntelliJ Community like any other library. Indeed, only the Ultimate version offers Hibernate support but you can still add the dependency to the project then configure everything manually.